# What are the negative side effects to increasing sequel max_connections and pool_timeout?

Tags: ruby, sqlite, sequel

I was getting `Sequel::PoolTimeout` errors and so I increased the :max_connections to 10 and the :pool_timeout to 10

```
DB = Sequel.connect('sqlite://streak.db', :max_connections => 10, :pool_timeout => 10)
```

Are there any negative side effects to increasing these values?

---

Here is a [link to an excerpt of code where the Pool Timeout happened](https://gist.github.com/oblakeerickson/9a97c550dbcd8132c269).

the `list` array only ever has around 100 items in it. In each thread it parses a web page for a value and inserts into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing max connections could leave your server thrashing as it tries to deal with too much.

Increasing timeout means it's going to take longer to timeout in situations where the query can never finish, e.g. locks.

What you should be doing is looking at the query(s) that are timing out and make them more performant.

No idea why you increased number of connections to fix a timeout problem, thats liable to make things worse...

Comment: I updated my question with some sample code. Since I only have about 100 threads at a time with inserts in them what should be the optimal pool_timeout value?

Comment: To improve my queries I could probably store all ~100 values in an array and then do one insert statement, but not sure the best way to improve the number of queries if I need to update multiple values instead of insert.

Comment: Have a look at this http://jokecamp.wordpress.com/2012/03/16/make-your-sqlite-bulk-inserts-very-fast-in-c/. 100 1 line inserts should take no time at all. Something to bear in mind, setting up and tearing down threads isn't cheap, and seeing as your real bottleneck is the dbms, a waste of time in this case...